# Uploads only work sporadically

Tags: networking, router, webserver, isp, upload

I am working on a web app, where users are allowed to upload video files. Video files get large quite quickly, to avoid timeouts on the server, I decided to split the file into many small packages of 3MB each, upload them, and then reassemble the file on the server.
This is done via AJAX and PHP, and it works great. 
I convert the file into binary, I upload it piece by piece to the server, once done I tell the server to reassemble it, and the server returns me the path of the completed file once done. I tried it with png files and with videos, and I tested different packet sizes. I also included this neat little display that tells you your current upload speed based on how long each package takes, and how long until it should be done.

Now here's where it gets crazy:
Occasionally my upload will be super slow (I usually get 0.5MB/s - those times I get 0.01MB/s), even when there is no other up- or download going on from my connection. I'll have to retry several times before it works okay again. Other times it uploads the first few packets just fine, and then suddenly it will do the rest of the packets at a rate of 3 packets every second. It appears as if my upload speed it through the roof, but nothing ever arrives on my server - in fact the video file will just stop playing at the same percentage that packages were dropped.

This seems to be an issue with my local connection, because I had no problem at other computers (though I can only always do a few tries).

I had my ISP come out, they updated some wiring and gave me a new router, but it hasn't fixed the issue. It happens on 2 different computers, both with wired connections.

My webhost said it's my ISP due to a couple of "Request Timed out" responsed when I run traceroute. Before the router got replaced a traceroute to google resulted in 7 out of 9 failed requests, now it's only 2 or 3 failures. There were 2 dropped requests to my server before and after the modem replacement.

Sending ping requests with the maximum permitted size of 65500 bytes always results in timeouts, both to google and to my server. Regular ping requests work okay.

Speed test shows exactly the results I should be getting.

What are my next steps to trouble shooting this? What could cause these issues? Why would it drop the uploads, and still give me a valid server response? Why does my ISP think my connection is all good, when I'm having such a hard time? The issue is rather intermittent, so I can't really show them anything.

**EDIT:**

As suggested, I ran a pathping, ans then also decided to post all the other results here. Hope nothing that I left uncensored leaves me open to vunlerability :D

Al these tests were made between 4 and 5 AM EST - so there shouldn't be too much other traffic going on.

[image: server results]
[image: google results]

Comment: The output from `pathping` to your server might provide some useful information. Please [edit] your question to include this.

Comment: Thanks! Would be good if I knew how to interpret these results... Definitely looks different when I ping google, though.

Comment: Nothing obvious. But we need the results to your *server* not *google*

Comment: I posted both: my server is the first picture with all the colors

Comment: My bad. Nothing obvious here either.

Comment: You need pathpings from when the speed is bad (to give to the ISP).

Comment: Thanks for your help. Why does the pathping to google consist of 10 addresses, whereas to my server it's only 3, and the third one has three stars  (meaning it timed out i suppose)?

Comment: 3 stars is not always timeout. You can get this if the router at hop 3 has ICMP disabled (for security reasons, some Routers do not allow you to ping them (ICMP is disabled due to a firewall or other security measures), and the block may affect Pathping, Ping and Tracert measurements but not actual server connections.)